# Rails: No route matches [POST] nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the routes.rb I have this nested resource

```
# OBSERVATIVE SESSIONS
resources :observative_sessions do
# OBSERVATIONS
  resources :observations
end
```

In observations_controller.rb

```
 def new
   @observative_session = ObservativeSession.find(params[:observative_session_id])
   @observation = Observation.new
   @observation.observative_session_id = @observative_session.id
 end

def create
  @observative_session = ObservativeSession.find(params[:observative_session_id])
  @observation = @observative_session.observations.build(observation_params)
  @observation.user_id = current_user.id

   respond_to do |format|
    if @observation.save
     format.html { redirect_to [@observative_session, @observation], notice: 'Observation was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @observation }
    else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @observation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And in observations_controller_test.rb I set up both observation and observative session. The test of new works just fine.

```
class ObservationsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

setup do
  @observative_session = observative_sessions(:one)
  @observation = observations(:two)
  sign_in users(:admin_user)
end

test "should get new" do
  get new_observative_session_observation_path(@observative_session)
  assert_response :success
end

test "should create observation" do
  assert_difference('Observation.count') do
   post observative_session_observation_path(@observative_session, @observation), params: { observation: { start_time: @observation.start_time, description: @observation.description, rating: @observation.rating, notes: @observation.notes, celestial_body_name: @observation.celestial_body_name, telescope_name: @observation.telescope_name, binocular_name: @observation.binocular_name, eyepiece_name: @observation.eyepiece_name, filter_name: @observation.filter_name, user_id: @observation.user_id, observative_session_id: @observation.observative_session_id }}
 end
```

But this is the error I get in the creation test

```
 test_should_create_observation 
 ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/observative_sessions/980190962/observations/298486374"
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you sure the ids are in the right place? have you tried switching parent and child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say POST `observation_session_observation_path(@observation_session, @observation)` you are telling it to post to a url the has both  `:observation_session_id` and an `:id` in the params, where the `id` is that of `@obseravtion`. However, POST paths for `create` actions don’t take that last `id` param (ostensibly you are creating a new record with that action).

Try dropping `@observation` from your path helper (and make sure you are using the correct create path: `observation_session_observations_path(@observation_session)`.
You can do `rake routes` to see your routes in your terminal, or `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` to see it in the browser.

I also see in your `new` action you are assigning the `observation_session_id` manually. I recommend you either do what you do later and call `@obervation_session.observations.build`, or `Observation.new(observation_session: @observation_session)`. You should avoid setting ids like that.

Comment: if I drop @observation I get this error `UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"observations", :observative_session_id=>#, longitude: #, altitude: 1, bortle: 1, sqm: #, completed: false, notes: "MyString">}, missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that your path should make `observation` plural. Updated my answer.